# Can I disable the PNP functionality on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, pnp

The reason I want to do this is most of the time I have the computer plugged into a 52"  LCD  in another room displaying information. Occasionally I need to update the software and to do so I need to see what I am doing so I plug a monitor in locally.

Problem is that it automatically adopts the device capabilities of the new monitor and thus changing the settings for the large screen. I then have to go to a networked administration panel for the software to update the resolution settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you don't want to disable Plug and Play, you want to disable the Display Data Channel (DDC)

> **On Microsoft Windows (Windows XP and newer), there is no software provided
>   option to disable plug and play
>   monitor detection.** This causes
>   problems with computer/monitor
>   switching applications and causes
>   computer games to select display
>   resolutions higher than the monitor is
>   physically capable of displaying
>   resulting in a garbled display.
>
> In these circumstances, it may be
>   necessary to remove pin 12 from the
>   monitor VGA cable, to disable plug and
>   play monitor detection. This allows
>   display resolution to be selected
>   manually and not overridden when the
>   display adapter is removed and
>   reinserted or the KVM switch is
>   operated.

the Pin # of course is different with HDMI or DVI connectors.

Comment: Ooh - that's  clever!

Answer (score 3):

According to this TechNet article [Plug and Play](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457175.aspx)

> Ability to disable: Plug and Play
>   cannot be disabled, because system
>   instability would result.

(I am assuming that is what you mean by "PNP").

Comment: I don't think there would be any system insability...maybe a hard to read monitor but that's about it :)

Answer (score -1):

Just open up your Services window (Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services) and stop 'Universal Plug and Play Device Host' and 'SSDP Discovery Service'.  Also set their start-up type to Disabled.

Comment: the SSDP service description says "Enables discovery of UPnP devices on your home network." I am looking for the monitor PNP.

Comment: This answer assumes you mean Universal Plug and Play (UPnP). If this isn't what you meant, then JP has it right.